# Access an AVAudioPlayer on its current thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, avaudioplayer

I'm using a series of `AVAudioPlayer`s concurrent with the main thread using `dispatch_async`. Before playing each one I must query, whether it is playing using its `isPlaying` method.

I am generally unfamiliar with `multithreading`, so how would I go about calling the `isPlaying` method on the thread that the `AVAudioPlayer` is currently working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the property `playing` directly on main thread because the operation is read, so it is safe I think :)

But you can't use it to judge if playback has completed as document says : **Important: Do not poll this property to determine when playback has completed, instead implement the specified delegate method**

You should use delegate and implement the method `- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag`, if the method is called, it means the player  stop.